# PHP follow users system issues with show one follow button per profile user

Tags: php

I have a follow PHP script for my users and works fine, but on profile user pages the follow button seems to have some issues. If I'm the only user registered on the site, it appears fine, only one following button but if I register one or more users to the site the follow button clones itself on the page, like in this screenshot, there are 3 following buttons and I want to be only one follow on the profile page. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

**Db structure:**

[image]

**Profile users page buttons with the issue:**

[image]

**This is the PHP code that i have inserted in profile page**

```
$get = new Main;
@$user_id = $_SESSION['user'];
$users = $get->users($user_id);
foreach ($users as $row) {
     echo ' '.(($row['receiver'] === $_GET['u'] && $row['sender'] === $user_id) ? '<div class="btn btn-success follow following" style="margin-top: -6px;" rel="'.$_GET['u'].'">Following</div>':' <div class="btn btn-danger follow" style="margin-top: -6px;" rel="'.$_SESSION['user'].'">Follow</div>').'';
   }
```

**The main PHP script**

```
    class Main{
//get all users from database where user_id not = your id
 public function users($user_id){
 global $pdo;
 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mls_users` U LEFT JOIN `follow` F on `f`.`receiver` = `U`.`id` AND CASE WHEN `F`.`sender` = ? THEN `F`.`receiver` = `U`.`id` END where `U`.`id` != ?");
 $query->bindValue(1,$user_id);
 $query->bindValue(2,$user_id);
  $query->execute();
 return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }
//this is our follow method
 public function follow($user_id,$follow_id){
 global $pdo;

 //insert into follow where user_id = you and follow_id is = follower
 $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `follow` (`sender`, `receiver`) VALUES (?, '".$_GET['u']."') ");
 //bind $user_id
 $query->bindValue(1,$user_id);
 //bind $follow_id
 //run query
 $query->execute();
 //add 1+ to follower profile
 $this->addNum($follow_id);
 }
 public function unFollow($user_id,$follow_id){
 global $pdo;
 //delete user_id and follow_id from follow 
 $query = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `follow` WHERE `sender` = ? and `receiver` = ?");
 //bind user_id
 $query->bindValue(1,$user_id);
 //bind follow_id
 $query->bindValue(2,$follow_id);
  //run query
  $query->execute();
  //add -1 to follower_count
  $this->removeNum($follow_id);
 }
 public function addNum($follow_id){
 global $pdo;
 //add 1 more num to follow_counter
 $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `mls_users` SET `followers_count` = `followers_count` +1 WHERE `id` = '".$_GET['u']."' ");
 //bind follow_id
 $query->bindValue(1,$follow_id);
 //run query
 $query->execute();
 }
 public function removeNum($follow_id){
 global $pdo;
 //remove 1 num from follow_counter
 $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `mls_users` SET `followers_count` = `followers_count` -1 WHERE `id` = ? ");
 //bind follow_id
 $query->bindValue(1,$follow_id);
 //run query
 $query->execute();
 }

public function getFollowedByUser($follow_id)
{
    global $pdo;
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `sender` FROM `follow` where `receiver` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1,$follow_id);
    $query->execute();
    $followed = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    //in case of failure you can check is $followed an array and do something if it's not
    if (is_array($followed)) {
        return $followed;
    }

    return array();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing follow for each $row of $users that fails

```
$row['receiver'] === $_GET['u'] && $row['sender'] === $user_id
```

First suggestion, use an "if" to improve readability of the code, the code as-is is too many characters crammed on a single line.

Second, since this is probably the profile of a single user, for each user, skip until you find the id you want to display data for (run continue; otherwise).

After that, print "already following" if it is being followed, or print the Follow box otherwise.

Third, it could be YOUR profile, and the function is meant to give you buttons to follow every other user on the database. Then edit the Follow to Follow Username. As you did not provide the html I can only guess the intent of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response @gia can u help me with the code and the modifications please? I'm new to this , thanks

Comment: you havent even posted the code to be helped with, I wont be fixing your code, best I'll do is post a pretty pseudocode of what you should be doing, or explain your logic mistake. For now perhaps you should check how many $users your query is returning and why, because it shouldn't return more than one and that's whats happening.

Comment: the query is returning all the users from users db , if i'm the only user it shows me only one follow buton and is ok, but when i register one or two users the follow buttons multiplicates each time a user is registering, the problem i think is on $query = $pdo->prepare(select.. from main php

Comment: yes, if you are going to draw one profile, you want only one user, find how to return only one user by its id. If you want to give follow buttons for every user on the site, then change the text of the buttons so you know who it will follow.

Comment: i have inserted "WHERE id=session id , but still nothing, same.

Comment: print your session id on your webpage, print your database query, test the printed query directly on the database